# Using Core Location to get coordinates and calcule who is 100 meters round wing

Tags: swift, core-location, appdelegate

Currently in my app I'm fetching the user coordinates. I need to keep this coordinates always updated so I placed the location code in app delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The code is:

```
let location = CLLocationManager()

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    location.delegate  = self
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    location.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    return true
```

Then, in the same AppDelegate.swift I implemented the delegate method to catch every location update as following:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print(locations)
}
```

The thing is that I'm always receiving nil values.

It is important to mention that I'm running the app over the simulator but in debug menu I simulate bicycle ride or even the Apple location.

What am I missing?

Of course I edited the plist with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manager.startUpdatingLocation()